# Hierarchy of Transformations, recursive function troubles

Tags: java, recursion, graph, transform, hierarchy

I began implementing a hierarchical scene graph in my Java/OpenGL project with basic entities/objects that have a position component, and that know both their parent entity and their child entity(s).

```
public class Entity
{
  private Entity parent;
  private ArrayList<Entity> children = new ArrayList<Entity>();
  private Vector3f pos = new Vector3f(0,0,0); //simplified transformation

  addChild(Entity child){...}
  setParent(Entity parent){...}

  public Vector3f getPos(){ return pos; }
  public void setPos(Vector3f pos){this.pos = pos}

//this is my non-functional attempt at creating hierarchical movement
  public void setRelativePos(Vector3f pos) 
  {
    this.setPos(parent.getPos().add(pos)); //position relative to parent

    for(Entity child : children)
    {
        //how the child relatives to the newly moved parent
        vec3 relativePos = child.getPos().sub(getPos());
        child.setRelativePos(relativePos);
    }
  }

}
```

What I had in mind was that children will move relative to their parent when the parent's position is changed/set.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something here, but ... isn't the whole point of having a hierarchy in form of a scene graph that you *only* have to apply the transformation to the parent (and the children will "follow" without the transform explicitly being set)? An aside: You should consider storing the transformation as a 4x4 matrix, because otherwise you'll get into trouble when you perform multiple transformations (rotations, translations, scalings...)

Comment: That is how I set my first one up, however I wanted to try doing so with this slightly different approach as well.  I am using a transformation matrix in my project, but for this example I figured that would distract from the real issue. (i.e. the non-functional recursive setPos)

Comment: Maybe this boils down to the question whether the "position" of a child is specified in coordinates that are *relative* to the parent position, or *absolute* (in world coordinates). But as far as I understood, your problem is solved now, so maybe it does not matter any more.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing, I think that when you move an Entity, you want to move all its children.

Your recursion has no stopping condition, and probably causes a stack overflow.
It also has a confusing name, `setPos`, which implies a simple setter, but that's not what it does. You should have different methods for each type of movevent. Ex : translate, rotate, etc...

You should do something like this :

```
// simple setter
public void setPos(Vector3f pos)
{
    this.pos = pos;
}

// translation movement
public void translate(Vector3f delta)
{ 
    // translate the current Entity
    setPos (getPos().add(delta));

    // translate the children
    for (Entity child : children)
        child.translate (delta);
}
```

Comment: You are correct, I apologize I botched the naming when I tried to simplify the code naming.  You picked up on this fortunately.  that 'translate' function however does not move the children correctly and is what I truly need help understanding.

Comment: @Watercycle `translate` would move each of the children by the same `delta` as the parent Entity. I thought that's what you wanted.